# Lambda for List within a List

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm sending SMSs in a batch of 20, so when I extract from my context/db all the SMSs that need sending I'd like to save them in a List of Lists of 20 SMS, like this`List<List<SMS>>`.

I'm currently doing it with a for loop but was wondering if there is a way to do it with a single Lambda, that I can't think of?

Comment: Hi! Great question. What you are looking for is how to "chunk" an IEnumerable. There's nothing built-in in the .NET framework, but it's not hard to implement. Since we already have a question for that, I have marked your question as a duplicate of that other question.

Comment: Something like this don't work .Select? IEnumerable<SmS> list = _dbContext.Sms.Where("Put there the condition").ToList();

Comment: @Heinzi there actually is something built into the .NET framework for this. `Partitioner.Create<SMS>(smsList)` and `partitioner.GetPartitions(Math.Ceiling(smsList.Count / 20.0))`

Comment: @p3tch: Nice, I did not know that!

Comment: @Heinzi after some testing, the LINQ solution is a lot faster in terms of creating a `List<List<T>>`. The partitioner might be better if you wanted to enumerate across each chunk on multiple threads via a `Parallel.ForEach` loop or something (rather than creating a collection of chunks to enumerate over later)